# How to avoid Google Drive/Gmail context menu disappearance using Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-inspector

I'm trying to inspect a context menu using Chrome, like the one from Google Drive or Gmail. I do right click and then `ctrl+shift+I`, but the menu disapears when it loses the focus.

Anybody knows how to inspect a context menu? Or maybe, some way to keep the menu visible after losing focus?

Comment: After you right click it and press ctrl+shift+I, I assume the menu is highlighted in the Elements tab? When it disappears, does it remain highlighted, i.e. it isn't destroyed? If so you should be able to untick style `{display:none}` on the menu element itself or it's parent which is hidden. Another possible option could be to get Dev Tools Settings open (F12 then F1 in windows), right click to show the menu, then tick Disable JavaScript. That may stop it being hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Drive application the contextual menu is triggered by Javascript. In order to suppress the element disappearance it's necessary to remove all the `Blur` listeners from the `Event Listeners` tab of Chrome Developer Tools attached to the element.

Comment: Tried your second approach with the Google Drive's context menu. However, it didn't work. It seems that the menu is populated after the "right-click" so, even with the element visible, I can not see what is inside.

Comment: that context menu is automatically regenerated each right click. by default it's empty.

- Open the Chrome Developer Tools
- Go to Elements tab
- Right click on an empty space, menu appears
- Select with the left click of the mouse the element above the element that was highlighted in the Elements panel (the latest element on the body probably), the menu should be visible
- Finally select with the left click on the elements panel that disappearing element, which you can now explore. If you click on the page with the mouse the menu will still disappear but you can select its parts on the panel

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking how to keep it visible. Is there a way to not lose the focus of an element when working with the Developer Tools? Or is just simply impossible to inspect this kind of menus?

Comment: Unfortunately not because it's not about the focus but about javascript events. What it's happening is that there is an event (document, body, on the element itself) that it's triggering the contents of the element. For this specific case your only chance is to remove the listener from `Event Listeners` tab but I think you would spend too much time searching for the proper event.

However for the majority of menu the suggestions should do the job.

Comment: Removing all the `Blur` listeners from the `Event Listener` tab did the trick! Thank you so much. I think you should edit your answer to include this.